# Unwanted second command prompt opens when running mongo.exe via command prompt

Tags: mongodb, command-line, command-prompt

I'm running a built meteor app on my local machine, and to quickly boot it up, I have a .bat file that runs the following:

```sh
start "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe"
set ROOT_URL=http://localhost
set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp
set PORT=80
node main.js
```

When I run the cmd to start up mongo.exe it opens up a *command prompt* with nothing in it, as if I opened it manually.

So now, I really would like to know: **why? and how to prevent this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `start`opens up a new command line window since it assumes your command must be run with cmd.exe. If you do not like to see the window try adding `/B` to your start command.
See `start /?` on the command line to check on other options you might find interesting.